# Data members as lvalue-reference or rvalue-copies

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, perfect-forwarding

Consider the following struct template:

```
template<typename T>
struct X
{
    X(T t) : t(std::forward<T>(t)) {}

    T t;
};
```

where T will either be a lvalue-reference (e.g, `const int&`) or a regular value (e.g, `int`). The idea is to use lvalue-reference whenever `X` is constructed from a *lvalue*, and a regular value when constructed from a *rvalue*.

Therefore, the following factory functions are defined to create an instance of `X` with such properties:

```
template<typename T>
X<const T&>
CreateX(const T& val)
{
    return X<const T&>(val);
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_rvalue_reference<T&&>::value, X<T>>::type
CreateX(T&& val)
{
    return X<T>(std::move(val));
}
```

So far, so good. If we now consider the struct template `Y`:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct Y
{
    Y(T t, U u) : t(std::forward<T>(t)), u(std::forward<T>(u)) {}

    T t;
    U u;
};
```

and we decide to make the same analogy as before for `X`, we end up with these four factory functions:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
Y<const T&, const U&>
CreateY(const T& t, const U& u)
{
    return Y<const T&, const T&>(t, u);
}

template<typename T, typename U>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_rvalue_reference<T&&>::value, Y<T, const U&>>::type
CreateY(T&& t, const U& u)
{
    return Y<T, const U&>(std::forward<T>(t), u);
}

template<typename T, typename U>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_rvalue_reference<U&&>::value, Y<const T&, U>>::type
CreateY(const T& t, U&& u)
{
    return Y<const T&, U>(t, std::forward<T>(u));
}

template<typename T, typename U>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_rvalue_reference<T&&>::value and std::is_rvalue_reference<U&&>::value, Y<T, U>>::type
CreateY(T&& t, U&& u)
{
    return Y<T, U>(std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<T>(u));
}
```

Is there an alternative way to obtain the same result, perhaps less verbose? Fortunately my application will not require more than two template data members, but several other classes like `Y` will be needed, requiring four factory functions for each of them.

Comment: `template<class T> X<T> make_X(T&& v){ return X<T>{std::forward<T>(v)}; }`, no silly SFINAE needed. This works for both lvalues and rvalues. I'd change the constructor to take `T&&` though, so you don't have an unnecessary move from ctor-parameter to member.

Comment: Thanks @Xeo, but this results in non-const lvalue-references when constructed from lvalues, and I would like them to be const lvalue-references. I agree with the use of `T&&` to avoid extra move.

Comment: Then make a simply trait that transform `T&` -> `T const&`. Shouldn't be hard.

Comment: I think it would be beneficial for me, and others in the future, if you could write an example using your idea and the transformation trait. Thanks once more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> this results in non-const lvalue-references when constructed from lvalues, and I would like them to be const lvalue-references

You can write a simple trait that transforms the lvalue references:

```
template<class T>
struct transform_parameter{ using type = T; };

template<class T>
struct transform_parameter<T&>{ using type = T const&; };

template<class T>
using TransformParameter = typename transform_parameter<T>::type;
```

And apply that for all relevant template parameters:

```
template<class T>
X<TransformParameter<T>> make_X(T&& v){
  return {std::forward<T>(v)};
}
```

I also used a braced-init-list (aka uniform initialization) here to save me from writing the type twice.

Comment: Thanks @Xeo. Not that your solution isn't good enough, but trying to explore more the dark corners of C++11, why this does not work: `template<typename T>
using TransformParameter = typename std::conditional<std::is_rvalue_reference<T&&>::value, T, typename std::add_const<T>::type>`?

Comment: @Allan: If `T` is `X&` for example, the `add_const` results in `X& const`, and since you can't const-qualify a reference, it's just dropped.

Comment: Is there an alternative using `std::conditional` and any other constructs available in the standard library?

Comment: @Allan: Yes, but it's kinda long-winded: `typename std::conditional<std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value, typename std::remove_reference<T>::type const&, T>::type`, basically removing the reference first, and then adding `const` and the reference back.

Comment: What about: `template<typename T>
using TransformParameter = typename std::conditional<std::is_rvalue_reference<T&&>::value, T, const T&>::type;`? Is it equivalent? I got it working somehow.

Comment: @Allan: That's exactly the same as before (there's a reason why I write my `const`s on the right of the type it appertains to: `const T&` == `T const&`, even if `T` == `X&`).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35076/discussion-between-allan-and-xeo)

Comment: @Allan: Is something still missing from the answer? If yes, please let me know. :)